# How do I copy CD to my Android cellphone using Lubuntu 18.10?

Tags: lubuntu, music, 18.10, cd, smartphone

How do I copy an audio CD to my Android 8.1.0 cellphone using Lubuntu 18.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did to get it working:

1. connect the phone using the provided USB cable.
2. verify it opens PCManfile and check it's listed via 'lsusb'.
3. `sudo apt install sound-juicer`
4. `sudo apt install lubuntu-restricted-extras`
5. reboot computer (steps 3-5 are #ubuntu ioria's instruction)
6. copy tracks from CD to computer with Sound Juicer, adding CD information to musicbrainz as needed.
7. search 'USB' in phone settings, tap to open settings page, change option from 'charge' to 'transfer files' to enable write permissions.
8. create a directory on your phone from within pcmanfile to store files (i chose the SD card)
9. copy-paste files between pcmanfile folders to copy tracks to your phone.
10. check to see if there's some 'safely remove' eject-external-drive feature on taskbar; disconnect cable from phone after all files have copied if not.
11. Navigate to the 'Files' app on phone by default. Navigate to the folder, change the listing setting to see filenames, and tap on file to play.
12. Consider installing better software to play files.

Comment: Good job! +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract files from your CD and copy them on your cellphone.
For extracting, I personally use Asunder, which is available in Lubuntu repository and pretty simple to use.
For copy, you'll need to connect your phone to your computer with Bluetooth or USB cable.

Comment: I connected the phone via USB but I do not have permission to write to the pcmanfm folder that opens for it. How do I copy files to it?

Comment: When you connect the phone, you should have an option that pops up on your phone in the notification area. I don't have the exact wording in English, but basically you can choose between "Power supply only", "File transfer" and "Multimedia device". The "multimedia device" is the right one for you. Once done, you should be able to copy your music files :-)